# Can I control a TMC2300 with ONLY the UART interface?

Tags: stepper-driver

I'm trying to design a board to drive some small stepper motors. They each take a phase current of about 180 mA. I want to try the TMC2300.

In the [datasheet](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC2300_datasheet_rev1.08.pdf) it says it is controled by either the dir/step pins or the UART and the dir/step pins (no example about using only the UART, without dir/step).

But [here on GitHub](https://github.com/markniu/PandaPi/wiki/How-to-run-TMC2209-with-UART-mode-%28V2.0-2.5%29), in the first picture, only the UART is connected. As the TMC2209 has a very similar control interface to the TMC2300's, I wonder if I can do that with a TMC2300 as well.

**I wonder if I can just connect the UART and leave dir/step floating (or tied to ground), so I need only one pin on my MCU for four motors.**

Comment: The datasheet is describing the "UART Single Wire Interface" which I believe is what you are looking for.

Comment: The datasheet contains the answer below figure 1.3: " Even motion without external STEP pulses is provided by an internal programmable step pulse generator: Just set the desired motor velocity. However, no ramping is provided by the TMC2300."

Answer (score 1):

> The datasheet contains the answer below figure 1.3: " Even motion
> without external STEP pulses is provided by an internal programmable
> step pulse generator: Just set the desired motor velocity. However, no
> ramping is provided by the TMC2300." – [Jens](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/313620/jens)

I got the information I need in the comment of the question.
Thanks alot!